# How to make a button send data to a django function with ajax

Tags: python, django, ajax

What I am trying to do is create an html button that grabs data from the page and sends it to a django function. The button is not linked to a form or anything. I am relatively new to django and I have tried a billion different approaches to this problem with no success. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first and easiest step to do this is to first create a new application called **ajax** and add it to the applications installed in the Django settings.

Go to **project_name/urls.py** and include ajax in a separate address:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('ajax/', include('ajax.urls')),
]
```

Then create a urls.py file in ajax and write it as an example:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'ajax'

urlpatterns = [
    path('First', views.FirstAjax, name='First'),
]
```

The app_name variable is written because it prevents hard code.

Go to **ajax/views.py** and create a new view called FirstAjax:

```py
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def FirstAjax(request):
    text = request.POST['text']
    return HttpResponse('All Done!')
```

Almost everything is great! If you want to write ajax as POST, you need to set the **csrf_exempt** decoratorso that Django does not react to CSRF Tokens. But if you want to do it with the GET method, you do not need this decorator.

Now you can use Ajax by adding JQuery to the project:

Simple example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id="myheader">My template</h2>
<button onclick="Ajax()">Click me!</button>

<script>
function Ajax() {
    $.post("{% url 'ajax:First' %}", {text:'Hello, Ajax!'}, function(response){ 
        console.log('Done');
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this little example has helped you and others.

Comment: You can actually send json data from javascript using ajax with `{"Content-Type":"application/json"}` but in the backend. You will have to use `request.data` to access that data.